# Creating isochrones in a travel-time map

Tags: routing, visualisation, isochrone, dijkstra

I'm working on building a travel-time map using time-expanded model and Java. I calculated the reachable points with Dijkstra's algorithm from a start point and within a specific travel time and I visualized the arcs of the reachable nodes like in the following image.

[image]

My question is how can I create isochrones? I want to implement a nice area visualization in an enclosed shape instead of visualizing arcs?
It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: These are typically implemented as "alpha shapes" computed from your edges that you've already identified. Give that term a search and see if it becomes clear.